# mipsel-linux-gcc: Command not found

Tags: android, linux, bash, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a kernel and rootfs using mipsel-linux-gcc compiler. Host machine is 64-bit, while the rootfs to be built is 32-bit.i tried to install ia32-libs and ia32-libs-multiarch. But failed. I've installed gcc-multilib using apt-get. However, I can't build.  I've updated PATH variable to the toolchain used.

```
echo $PATH
```

usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin

Error I get :

```
root@android-build:uclinux-rootfs# make vmlinuz-7425b0-android
make TFTPHOST=android-build TFTPDIR=/tftpboot/$USER TFTPPATH=$USER defaults-7425b0-android
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/uclinux-rootfs'

WARNING: using toolchain binaries in:
/opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin

The recommended toolchain for this release is:
stbgcc-4.5.3-2.4

perl -w bin/config.pl save_defaults 7425b0-android
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make -f Makefile savedefconfig
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
scripts/kconfig/conf --savedefconfig=defconfig Kconfig
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make -j1 silentoldconfig
make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/uclinux-rootfs'

WARNING: using toolchain binaries in:
/opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin

The recommended toolchain for this release is:
stbgcc-4.5.3-2.4

make -C linux ARCH=mips silentoldconfig
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make -f Makefile silentoldconfig
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make -C linux ARCH=mips prepare scripts
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make -f Makefile prepare
/bin/sh: mipsel-linux-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: mipsel-linux-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: mipsel-linux-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: mipsel-linux-gcc: not found
make[4]: mipsel-linux-gcc: Command not found
make[4]: Entering directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
CHK     include/linux/version.h
CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: mipsel-linux-gcc: not found
make[5]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make[4]: *** [prepare0] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make[3]: *** [prepare] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/linux'
make[2]: *** [silentoldconfig] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/uclinux-rootfs'
make[1]: *** [defaults-7425b0-android] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/kernel/android/kernel-3.3-1.2-7425b0/uclinux-rootfs'
make: *** [vmlinuz-7425b0-android] Error 2
```

But what I get for which mipsel-linux-gcc gave the right answer

```
which mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc
/opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc
```

What could be the variable I need to export?

Comment: Try to invoke `/opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc -v`, if the system still says *not found*, then you don't have proper 32-bit libs. Try also `ldd /opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc`.

Comment: ldd shows "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: I have expected something like this. ldd doesn't understand its format. What do `ls -l /opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc` and `file /opt/toolchains/stbgcc-4.5.3-1.1/bin/mipsel-linux-uclibc-gcc` say? Just to make sure, these simple things are O.K.

Answer (score 1):

I had that 'command not found' problem. Try to install ia32-libs or if that is not found try suggested lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 packages. That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: While this may answer the question, keep in mind that this question was asked two years ago, and the Original Poster most likely is not still encountering this issue.  Any answer should therefore be directed toward more current users who might also have the same problem, and should also include some versioning information for the libraries suggested.